# Custom icon for status when using service Android

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a foreground service. With it I have to show notification and add an icon to the status bar like this:

```
    val notification = Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("adf")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_input_component_24)
    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_input_component_24,2)
    .setContentText("ewr").build()
    startForeground(1, notification)
```

Text displayed correctly but icon doesn't changed and shows only the default Android's icon. How can I add a custom icon?

Comment: what is the android target? in all version you have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this into your android manifest xml?

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- Add your meta-data here-->
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_input_component_24" />

    ...
</application>
```